# javascript - how to make reusable function with id as parameter?

Tags: javascript

Hello guys how do I put parameters on "onclick" function.
I want to make reusable function so other id can use the same function on "Onclick" function

```
   <style type="text/css">
        #time1, #time2 {
            width: 95px;
        }        
    </style>

    <form>
        <label for="time1">time</label>
        <input id="time1" type="text" name="time1">
        <input type="checkbox" onclick="enableInputTime('time1')"> Input Time?
        <br>
        <label for="time2">time</label>
        <input id="time2" type="text" name="time2">
        <input type="checkbox" onclick="enableInputTime('time2')"> Input Time?
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function enableInputTime(id) {
            var id = document.getElementById(id);
            if(id.type === 'text') {
                id.type = 'time';
                id.step = "1";
            } else {
                id.type = 'text';
            } 
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: as much as that is not how I'd write the code you put in the question, is there something wrong with your code? is it not working as expected?

Comment: @TyQ. well i am not using jQuery man, i am trying to use plain javascript

Comment: could it be the simple typo? calling function `enableInputTime` vs defining function `enableInputTime1` ? because, if you fix that typo, there's nothing inherently wrong with the code, it does what it looks like it should do

Comment: @JaromandaX if you change to "var id = document.getElementById('time1');" thats working. but only 1 id. I want to make the function reusable so not just 1 id only. Any idea how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You named your function `enableInputTime1` but you tried to call `enableInputTime` in the HTML.  If you make the names agree your code does exactly what you want.

Comment: thx man just figured out

Answer (score 0):

There you go, note that I declare the function as a variable and fixed the name of the function `enableInputTime`

```html
 <style type="text/css">
        #time1, #time2 {
            width: 95px;
        }        
    </style>

    <form>
        <label for="time1">time</label>
        <input id="time1" type="text" name="time1">
        <input type="checkbox" onclick="enableInputTime('time1')"> Input Time?
        <br>
        <label for="time2">time</label>
        <input id="time2" type="text" name="time2">
        <input type="checkbox" onclick="enableInputTime('time2')"> Input Time?
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var enableInputTime = function(id) {
            var id = document.getElementById(id);
            if(id.type === 'text') {
                id.type = 'time';
                id.step = "1";
            } else {
                id.type = 'text';
            } 
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: What's gained by declaring an anonymous function and assigning to a variable here?

Comment: @DanielMcLaury is loaded before any code executes

Comment: I agree that the OP's function gets defined at parse time whereas yours is defined later, at runtime.  What I don't understand is why that's desirable in this situation.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury, well I just prefer used named functions when I use something like `document.getElementById(id)` inside of the function, but nothing special with this case, it can be any convention